# Solitidy smart contract: invalid address (mapping)

Tags: solidity

I'm currently trying to deploy basic smart contracts for traceability of products. I have an issue using mappings.

Basically, I have a (address => bool) mapping, and I can't change the value for a specific address using the following syntax:

```
TrackList[address] = true;
```

address is an argument of my function, which is called with:

```
Traceability.Track(0x...);
```

and I get the following error in geth console:

```
Error: invalid address
at web3.js:3930:15                                                                                              
at web3.js:3756:20                                                                                              
at web3.js:5025:28                                                                                              
at map (<native code>)                                                                                          
at web3.js:5024:12
at web3.js:5050:18
at web3.js:5075:23
at web3.js:4137:16
at apply (<native code>)
at web3.js:4223:16
```

Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: Are you calling this method from js?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in your address argument as a string from the client:

```
Traceability.Track('0x...');
```